# why are my icons showing up like this? this is react-native-vector-icons

Tags: javascript, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1OTc.png)

When I insert the icon in my code when it appears in the emulator it appears as it appears in the print

Comment: Show what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

This caused by the app JS bundle and font assets are not in sync.

**Following step below as per official documentation**

This method has the advantage of fonts being copied from this module at build time so that the fonts and JS are always in sync, making upgrades painless.

Edit android/app/build.gradle ( NOT android/build.gradle ) and add the following:

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
To customize the files being copied, add the following instead:

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```